# GPML gives too large length scale when optimising hyperparameters

Tags: regression, matlab, gaussian-process

I recently started trying to apply Gaussian process regression to a problem, using the MATLAB GPML toolbox. The problem has five (or more) input variables, but for now I'm just looking at one of them.

With manually selected hyperparameters, I get reasonable-looking output, but my problem is that when I `minimize()` the hyperparameters, I get a very large length scale, thus producing a flat mean and covariance function.

If I run the following code, `hyp2.cov = [5.4, 1.1]` after the call to minimize, so the length scale is `exp(5.4)=214`, even though the data points are on the interval [-0.14, 0.06].

Could anyone tell me why this is so?

```
x=[-0.0350; 0.0550;-0.0830;-0.1360; 0.0190];
y=[3.0700;3.3200;3.0400;3.0600;2.9200];
covfunc = @covSEiso; hyp2.cov = [0; 0]; hyp2.lik = log(0.1);
likfunc = @likGauss; sn = 0.1; hyp2.lik = log(sn);
hyp2 = minimize(hyp2, @gp, -100, @infExact, [], covfunc, likfunc, x, y);
```

Comment: Remember EB can fall into local minima. Try initializing hyperparameters at different locations.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried a few different locations, but got the same results. However, the problem rather seems to be limited data. If I just copy the few data points I have and shuffle them around a bit, I do get more sensible hyperparameters. I suppose that with just 5 points, a flat mean with large covariance is probably a pretty reasonable estimate after all.

Comment: that was going to be my other concern. :)

Comment: Try to place prior for distribution of covariance function parameters. As you place correct prior you obtain solution with desirable behaviour i.e. you get rid of "bad" solutions.